# How to structure record as days within week, weeks within month etc

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb

I am retrieving booking records from a mongo database but want to organise the collection of records returned so that the embedded structure is like so:

```
2018
{
  january
  {
    {booking_id: 1, date: 2018-01-01T20:00:00Z}
    {booking_id: 2, date: 2018-01-02T20:00:00Z}
  }
  february
  {
    {booking_id: 3, date: 2018-02-01T20:00:00Z}
    {booking_id: 4, date: 2018-02-02T20:00:00Z}
  }
  ..
}
2017
..
```

I am able to group them by date like so:

```
@bookingsdaily = @bookings.all.group_by(&:date)
```

but am unsure how I could do this and create additional layers. I was thinking I should possibly group by year first and then with each year collection sort by month then day but not sure how exactly I would achieve this. Any pointers or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: you can try aggregate pipeline `db.books.aggregate(
  [
    {$group: {_id : { year : {$year : "$date"}, month : {$month : "$date"}, week : {$week : "$date"}}, books : {$push : "$$ROOT"}}},
  ]
).pretty()` the result will be grouped by year, month and week but not in the json structure you've posted

Comment: @Saravana why not give it as an answer?

Comment: are you storing date as string?

Comment: I ended up using that `@bookingdates = Booking.collection.aggregate([ { "$group" => { "_id" => {day: { "$dayOfMonth": "$date" }, month: { "$month" => '$date'}, year: { "$year" => '$date' } }, bookings: { "$push" => '$$ROOT'} } } , {'$sort' => {"_id.year" => -1}} ] ).to_a`. Thanks for the help @Saravana. If you post it as an answer I can accept. Any other tips when dealing with aggregate pipeline are always appreciated.